# How to get vertices in shortest path using python igraph?

Tags: python, graph, igraph, shortest-path, vertices

I can create a very simple graph using python-igraph...

```
import igraph
g=igraph.Graph.TupleList([("a", "b", 3.0), ("c", "d", 4.0), ("a", "c", 5.0)], weights=True)
print( igraph.summary(g, full=True) )
```

which looks like this:

```
IGRAPH UNW- 4 3 --
+ attr: name (v), weight (e)
+ edges (vertex names):
      edge   weight
[0]   a--b        3
[1]   c--d        4
[2]   a--c        5
```

Finding the shortest path is easy!

```
source = g.vs[0]             // vertex "a"
target = g.vs[len(g.vs)-1]   // vertex "d"
g.shortest_paths(source=source, target=target, weights='weight')
```

which prints the result:

```
[[9.0]]
```

I am happy that the edge weight of the shortest path is 9.0. However, I would like to obtain the actual vertices and edges that make up the shortest path of the graph. It would be nice to get an object that looks like this:

```
shortestPath = [("a", "c", 5.0), ("c", "d", 4.0)]
```

Can python-igraph provide this to me? I have searched the documentation with no luck...

Comment: Answer is:
`get_shortest_paths(v, to=None, weights=None, mode=OUT, output="vpath")`